# Get records from one table to other table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I am using sql server 2008 for my project. I have two tables named 1. `Customer_Invoice` 2. `Orders.`
and both the table have `Customer_Invoice_ID` column. In `Customer_Invoice` table as `PK` and in `Orders` table as `FK`.

Now my requirement is to get `top 100 records from Customer_Invoice` table and `then for each Customer_Invoice_ID, i want all records from orders table`. So i want all the records from the order table which Customer_Invoice_ID is present in Customer_Invoice table.

So first,

```
Select top 100 * from Customer_Invoice
```

and then for each `Customer_Invoice_ID` get records from `Order table`.

Can anyone guide me how to write query for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Customer_Invoice_ID IN 
            (Select top 100 Customer_Invoice_ID from Customer_Invoice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM dbo.[Order] o
OUTER APPLY (
     SELECT TOP 100 * 
     FROM dbo.Customer_Invoice
     WHERE t.Customer_Invoice_ID = o.Customer_Invoice_ID
) t
```